# vue2 get component instance from selector?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I've some dynamic (`v-for`) [non-parent-child](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)  component and I'd like to access their methods from a non-parent parent, I know about events and `ref`, but wondering if there's a way to access component instances from a given selector (found nothing about in the documentation).